# Best approach for ensuring uniform function signatures

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have an application where a user writing client code could select one of a number of functions in configuration. It makes sense that each of these presents the same function signature, *e.g.*,

```
def strawberry(param_1, param_2, param_3) -> float:
    (body of function)

def banana(param_1, param_2, param_3) -> float:
    (body of function)

def apricot(param_1, param_2, param_3) -> float:
    (body of function)
```

*etc*.

Now, one way to enforce this would be to create some wrapper and a little factory or switch, *e.g.*,

```
def the_only_foo(param_1, param_2, param_3, algorithm) -> float:
    if algorithm == 'strawberry':
        (do the strawberry stuff here)
    elif algorithm == 'banana':
        (do the banana stuff here)
    elif algorithm == 'apricot':
        (do the apricot stuff here)
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid algorithm specified!!")
```

There's no inheritance for functions, so how best to go about this? Stick with something like the above? Trust myself and other developers who may contribute new algorithms (*e.g.*, `lemon` and `peach`)? Ideas?

Comment: Are all these functions in a class?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not at present.

Comment: This looks like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please state what you're trying to accomplish by postfixing functions with sequential numbers (show/explain the use case without a contrived example). Did you mean to use a list or dict?

Comment: @ggorlen Only meant to distinguish between functions without getting into specifics. I see your point though and have edited to avoid confusion -- did not mean to use a list or dict. Thanks.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use classes? Then you can take advantage of inheritance and the `abc.ABC` class to ensure uniformity

Comment: The edit doesn't help clarify what you're really trying to accomplish. Both of your proposals are very questionable practices, but without knowing what you aim to achieve, there's no way to provide an answer that does follow good practices. The `lemon`/`strawberry` fruit stuff just looks like a nightmare to maintain. What do those mean? See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) in particular.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying not to get into the specifics of the individual algorithms hence the fruit names. But by way of example, one might have different methods to integrate a differential equation (*e.g.*, Euler or Heun), different methods of calculating minimum energy, or different encryption algorithms. Client code specifies the algorithm to use by name. Hence the question. Does that help?

Comment: That helps, but it seems like the answer is trivial: give the functions their usual names and have the user call them, right? Skip the conditional and the numerical postfixes. If you need to organize them in a structure, static class methods are possible or use a dict or list.

Comment: @ggorlen Precisely the motivation for the question. I don't think the conditional is a good solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using an `abc.abstractmethod`.  Here you can simply show the `Fruit` class and all derived classes must implement this member with the same args.

```
import abc


class Fruit(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_fruity(self, a, b, c) -> float:
        pass


class Strawberry(Fruit):

    def get_fruity(self, a, b, c):
        return 1.0


class Banana(Fruit):
    def get_fruity(self, a, b, c):
        return 2.0


class Apricot(Fruit):
    def get_fruity(self, a, b, c):
        return 3.0


def strawberry(param_1, param_2, param_3) -> float:
    return Apricot().get_fruity(param_1, param_2, param_3)


def banana(param_1, param_2, param_3) -> float:
    return Banana().get_fruity(param_1, param_2, param_3)


def apricot(param_1, param_2, param_3) -> float:
    return Apricot().get_fruity(param_1, param_2, param_3)
```

Comment: While a class may be a useful organizational tool, if the functions are stateless, creating heap allocated instances per call only to garbage collect them immediately is wasteful. Consider using static methods.